# how to pass value to get List getEmployee() in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My project is java spring mvc. I want data list for front end with specific employee.

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setUp(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute employeedetail employeedetail) {


    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String empNumer = auth.getName();
    employeedetail employee = employeeServices.getEmployee(empNumer);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userId", employee.getEmpNumer());
    return "home";

}
```

In here I got log in user number so I want get list of detail of employee as a array list.

Comment: I don't understand your question. you need improve the wording and show more code

Comment: my problem is like this I have entity called employee and roster,so in above controller redirect to the login user page and all the employee detail can get to that page called home.then i want show that login user's roster from jquery datatable so i want data list to front end.this is my question? my dao class is like this`@Override
 public List getDetail(String empNumer){
  return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("Select empNumer,firstName,email from eroster where empNumer = :empNumer ").setString( "empNumer", empNumer ).list();
 }`

Comment: If you wanna send the list from the controller to the page, you can do: `model.addAttribute("employeeDetail", dao.getDetail(empNumer));`